# programing in C - .TXT load, print and save

Tags: c, printing, load, save

I need som help with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    char text[500]; /* Create a character array that will store all of the text in the file */
    char line[100]; /* Create a character array to store each line individually */
    
    FILE *file; /* Create a pointer to the file which will be loaded, to allow access to it */
    char fileName[30]; /* Create a character array to store the name of the file the user want to load */
    
    printf("Enter the name of the file containing ship information: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    
    /*Try to open the file specified by the user. Use error handling if file cannot be found*/
    file = fopen(fileName, "r"); /* Open the file specified by the user in 'read' mode*/
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        perror("The following error occurred: ");
        printf("Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File loaded. "); /* Display a message to let the user know
                                  * that the file has been loaded properly */
    }

    while(fgets(line, 100, file)!="\n")
    {
    }
    
    return 0;
    return (printf);
}
```

1)I want a menu for exemple :[l]oad  - [s]ave,  when I write "L" then I go to :

```
printf("Enter the name of the file containing ship information: ");
```

2. and I need a help with how to make a print to the txt file and how I can save it again with Another name I mean I choose the name .

Comment: Is this `return (printf);` a part of your program or a typo?

Comment: Probably you should elaborate on `scanf("%s", fileName);` as there is only room for 30 chars in fileName `char fileName[30];`. Imagine a user entering. "ThisFilenameIsALittleBitTooLongToFitInOurThirtyCharacterArray" or something like that.

Comment: alright , i'll try it ;) thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question 1 i.e. menu,
1)I want a menu for exemple :[l]oad - [s]ave, when I write "L" then I go to :

printf("Enter the name of the file containing ship information: ");

For this part,
    char inpChar;

```
do {
    printf("enter menu: [l]oad - [s]ave\n");
    scanf("%c", &inpChar);
} while((inpChar != 'l') && (inpChar != 'L') && (inpChar != 's') && (inpChar != 'S'));

if((inpChar == '1') || (inpChar == 'L'))
{
     printf("Enter the name of the file containing ship information: ");
     scanf("%s", filename);
}
```

For Q2 of printing to file,

```
file = fopen(filename, "a");
fprintf(file, "%s", line);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: I Think i got it , Im trying to fix it and thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I actually did a "file en/decrypter" recently. Not only does it have a pretty decent options menu, it also deals with filehandeling. Not the best comments and maybe a bit messy, but I´m pretty sure, if you read it, you will find it usefull, or at least get some insperation.

I recomment reading the "man()" function first, or compile and run it with "./a.out -h" to get a easier overview of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* ENCRYPTING FILES
  15.Dec.2012
  By Morten Lund */

#define ALPHA "\\~!?=#)%(&[{]}|@,.;:-_*^+<>1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFG HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/$"
#define CRYPT_ALPHA "/#UwVM{>12E+j,4amN&stin]Ao_6}Q|7q[!f(FJKcLBz^)XYdhZkl9e?Wv@u;35yHrg< P*pSGTx=Ib~%R0$O.8:-DC\\"
#define ALPHA_SIZE sizeof(ALPHA)

void man();
void crypt(FILE *fpIN, FILE *fpOUT, char mode);
void replaceOriginal(char *inFileName, char *outFileName);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

// Check if ALPHA and CRYPT_ALPHA is same size
if (sizeof(ALPHA) != sizeof(CRYPT_ALPHA)) {
    printf("ALPHA and CRYPT_ALPHA is not the same size!!");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

/*------START-------OPTIONS MENU:-------START-----*/

char *inFileName;               // Input file name/dir
char *outFileName = "out.txt";  // Output file name/dir

char mode = 'N';                // E=encrypt, D=decrypt mode. N=Not set
int replaceMode = 0;            // Replace original file :default is OFF

int x;
for (x = 1; x < argc; x++) {

    if (strcmp(argv[x], "-e") == 0) {    // Encryption mode
        mode = 'E';
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[x], "-d") == 0) {    // Decryption mode
        mode = 'D';
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[x], "-r") == 0) {    // Replace original file
        replaceMode = 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[x], "-f") == 0) {    // Input file option
        x++;
        inFileName = argv[x];
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[x], "-o") == 0) {    // Output file option
        x++;
        outFileName = argv[x];
    }
}
/*------END-------OPTIONS MENU:--------END-------*/

FILE *fpIN, *fpOUT; // Creating file pointer to in and output file

// Check if mode is set to E OR D. Check if input and output file is set.
if (mode == 'E' || mode == 'D' && inFileName != NULL && outFileName != NULL) {

    // If inFileName exists and is readable, it is opened, else return EXIT_FAILURE 
    if ((fpIN = fopen(inFileName, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\nERROR! Input file: %s\nFile does not exist or is not readable!\n\n", inFileName);

        fclose(fpIN);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Check if Output file allready exist.
    if ((fopen(outFileName, "r")) != NULL) {
        printf("\nOutput file: %s\nFile allready exist, do you want to overwrite it? [Y/N]: ", outFileName);

        char choice;
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        while (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // If outFileName is writeble, it is opened, else return EXIT_FAILURE
    if ((fpOUT = fopen(outFileName, "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("\nERROR! Output file: %s\n File or location is not writeble!\n\n", outFileName);


        fclose(fpIN);  // Closing input pointer
        fclose(fpOUT); // and output pointer
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("\nInput file: %s\n", inFileName);
    printf("Output file: %s\n", outFileName);
    printf("mode (E)ncryption (D)ecrypting: %c\n", mode);
    crypt(fpIN, fpOUT, mode);

    fclose(fpIN);  // Closing input pointer
    fclose(fpOUT); // and output pointer
} else
    man();

// Check if set, and if, then replace original file
if (replaceMode)
    replaceOriginal(inFileName, outFileName);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void crypt(FILE *fpIN, FILE *fpOUT, char mode) {

char *alphaFrom, *alphaTo;      // Alphabet to copy from, to

if (mode == 'E') {               // If mode=Encrypt, copy from ALPHA to CRYPT_ALPHA
    alphaFrom = ALPHA;
    alphaTo = CRYPT_ALPHA;
}
else if (mode == 'D') {          // If mode=Decrypt, copy from CRYPT_ALPHA to ALPHA
    alphaFrom = CRYPT_ALPHA;
    alphaTo = ALPHA;
}

char curChar; int i;                        // Current character, and counter (i)
while ((curChar = fgetc(fpIN)) != EOF) {    // Assign curChar from fpIN as long it's not EOF

    for (i = 0; i < ALPHA_SIZE; i++) {      // For every character in alphabet size

        if (curChar == alphaFrom[i])        // If character = alphaFrom, replace with alphaTO
            fputc(alphaTo[i], fpOUT);
    }

    if (curChar == '\n')                    // Finding \n and inserting with \n
        fputc('\n', fpOUT);
    if (curChar == '\t')                    // Finding \t and inserting with \t
        fputc('\t', fpOUT);
}

}

void replaceOriginal(char *inFileName, char *outFileName) {

    if (remove(inFileName) == 0) {                  // Remove inFileName
        if (rename(outFileName, inFileName) == 0)   // Rename outFileName
            printf("File %s successfully replaced\n", inFileName);
    } else
        printf("Couldn't delete %s.. Replace failed", inFileName);
}

void man() {

printf("\n.....Simple Crypter.....\n\nUsage: sCrypter [Arguments] -f [input file]\n\tOr: sCrypter -e -f file.txt\n\tOr: sCrypter -d -r -f file.txt\n\tOr: sCrypter -e -f file.txt -o file2.txt\n\n");
printf("  [-h]  This page.\n");
printf("  [-f]  Set input file.\n");
printf("  [-o]  Set output file [OPTIONAL] default: out.txt.\n");
printf("  [-e]  Encrypting input file.\n");
printf("  [-d]  Decrypting input file.\n");
printf("  [-r]  Replace the input file with the new output file.\n\n");

printf("Warning! If [-r] is used, out.txt will be used as tmp file.\n");
printf("[-o] can be used in combination with [-r] to insure that another tmp file is used.\n\n");
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.